# Permissions in Samba

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba, file-permissions

I am facing this problem. I am running a samba server for some windows clients. I have 100 users in this samba share and all of them are belong to the primary group "smbusers". Now, I created an excel file in this samba server and i want to be read-write-execute only by 3 users, and the rest of 97 to be able only to read the excel file. I mentioned, that all this 100 users are part of many groups.Any help will be very appreciated.
Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new group 'rwnewfile' with groupadd.

Add your three special users:

```
usermod -Ga rwnewfile user1
usermod -Ga rwnewfile user2
usermod -Ga rwnewfile user3
```

I will assume you're using ext4 which supports acl by default. I also assume your group 'smbusers' already has r-x access.

```
 $    getfacl /opt/example/file.xls
  # file: /opt/example/file.xls
  # owner: root
  # group: smbusers
  user::rwx
  group::r-x
  mask::rwx
  other::r-x
```

Now we add your new group:

```
sudo setfacl -m g:rwnewfile:rwx /opt/example/file.xls
```